# SqlBulkCopy Column Mappings 500 Columns Plus New Columns

Tags: sql

I searched through several posted questions related to SqlBulkCopy and ColumnMappings and could not find a solution. I am using C# ASP .NET MS VS 2010 with SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have been using SqlBulkCopy to load a staging table with data from a DataTable Source. I want to add a ColumnMappings property to my SqlBulkCopy object but since I have so many columns I am trying to avoid listing out all 500+ columns in my code that I need mapped to columns in the DB staging table.

The reason why I need to use ColumnMappings is that I have to drop and add columns so the schema is dynamic which is not a good design but for this purpose it is ok by our internal client and they understand the risks.

I also have captured all the column names into a collection. I don't think ColumnMappings method takes a collections as source and destination.

I've thought about writing two SqlBulkCopy objects to handle this but not sure that would work. Another option would be to use T-SQL..

What is the best way to handle this or what solution would you suggest I explore?

```
 --set the connection string
//
 string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CPDM"].ToString();  
//
SqlConnection scCPDM = new SqlConnection(strConn);
//
//
--create the SqlBulkCopy opbject
//
SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(strConn);
bulkcopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 3000;
bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "CPDE_STAGING";
//
--need a to map all column mappings + new columns
--looking to do something like this -->  bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(*,*);
--then this ----> bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(new_column,new_table_column);
--for each new column

bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dtNewRaw);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using this and works great.

```
            //sqlbulkcopy does a blind insert into the db table.
            //we have to add a column mapping property to tell
            //sqlbulkcopy how to map each column from source to destination correctly
            foreach (string sColumn in columnNamesNew)
            {
                string sNewColumn = sColumn.Replace(' ', '_');
                bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(sColumn, sNewColumn);

            }
```